# Objective - C Getting blank value for CFBundleShortVersionString - App Version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am programmatically getting the App Version and getting the blank value for the app version. I am also getting 0 for build number - kCFBundleVersionKey.

Below is the code for the same.

```
NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString * build = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

I have already added both the values in info.plist file and General tab for the Target.

Comment: Which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 8.3.3.

I have noticed a thing. These values are missing in the info.plist file I am opening through below path.

[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]

When I open the plist file located at the above path these values are missing but these values are present in the info,plist file which is in the xcode main bundle and build settings.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's helpful for you

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSLog(@"Version %@",version);
```

OR

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary];

NSString *version = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *build = infoDictionary[(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSString *bundleName = infoDictionary[(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];
```

Comment: It is not working. I think the issue is something else. I have commented it in the question.

Comment: are you add the General -> Identity -> Version and Build set the value on this path???

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Comment: The value is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

this code is working in my project for getting Version